# Unable to identify which file association is responsible for opening a .c file extension in Windows

Tags: file

I'm attempting to get a grasp on how file associations work in Windows.  My understanding is that there are two command line tools, assoc and ftype, that are used to alter the way in which programs are opened.

I wanted to change the default program for opening C files from Visual Studio to notepad and was looking for a .c extension in the output of assoc but am unable to find neither a .c or .h extension.

I tried changing the default program through the GUI and send the output of ftype and assoc to files before and after the change but was unable to find any difference.  So my question is how is windows detecting C files when there does not seem to be any association or corresponding entry in ftype for it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `assoc`/`ftype` are just for running scripts on the command line (e.g. you could associate `.pl` with `perl.exe` and then run `script.pl` directly instead of `perl script.pl`). What happens when you open the file in explorer is a separate registry setting.

Comment: Maybe look in the registry? Does `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.c` exist? For me, Visual Studio puts `VisualStudio.c.5cdf67e3` in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.c\OpenWithProgids` , which is at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.c.5cdf67e3`

Comment: Yes there are values in the registry with the .c extension.  Thank you both for your answers.  Looks like next up for me is to do some reading on the registry and try to wrap my head around how that works!